# Not getting all reviews while scraping reviews in flipkart product?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to data science and learning how to do web scrapping.
I am trying to scrap reviews on particular products, but I am not able to scrap the whole reviews.

By code is working fine with no error, actually first it was giving error as bellow then i changed the code .

**Old Code:**

```
def perform_scraping(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
    all_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="_1AtVbE col-12-12")
    del all_div[0]
    for review in range(1,len(all_div)):
        rating = all_div[review].find("div", class_ = "_3LWZlK _1BLPMq").text
        review_title = all_div[review].find("p","_2-N8zT").text
        all_reviews.append((rating,review_title))

all_reviews = []
for page_number in range(1,2):
    i = page_number
    link = f"https://www.flipkart.com/prowl-tiger-shroff-push-up-board-upper-body-workout-push-up-bar/product-reviews/itm0487671f4df34?pid=BAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZ&lid=LSTBAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZVCWDQ9&marketplace=FLIPKART&page={i}"
    perform_scraping(link)
all_reviews
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 15
     13     i = page_number
     14     link = f"https://www.flipkart.com/prowl-tiger-shroff-push-up-board-upper-body-workout-push-up-bar/product-reviews/itm0487671f4df34?pid=BAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZ&lid=LSTBAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZVCWDQ9&marketplace=FLIPKART&page={i}"
---> 15     perform_scraping(link)
     16 all_reviews

Cell In[3], line 7, in perform_scraping(link)
      5 del all_div[0]
      6 for review in range(1,len(all_div)):
----> 7     rating = all_div[review].find("div", class_ = "_3LWZlK _1BLPMq").text
      8     review_title = all_div[review].find("p","_2-N8zT").text
      9     all_reviews.append((rating,review_title))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I am sharing the updated code bellow please help.

**Updated Code:**

```
def perform_scraping(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    all_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="_1AtVbE col-12-12")
    del all_div[0]
    all_reviews = []
    for review in range(0, len(all_div)):
        rating_elem = all_div[review].find("div", class_="_3LWZlK _1BLPMq")
        review_title_elem = all_div[review].find("p", class_="_2-N8zT")

        if rating_elem is not None and review_title_elem is not None:
            rating = rating_elem.text
            review_title = review_title_elem.text
            all_reviews.append((rating, review_title))
    
    return all_reviews

all_reviews = []
for page_number in range(1, 2):
    link = f"https://www.flipkart.com/prowl-tiger-shroff-push-up-board-upper-body-workout-push-up-bar/product-reviews/itm0487671f4df34?pid=BAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZ&lid=LSTBAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZVCWDQ9&marketplace=FLIPKART&page={page_number}"
    all_reviews.extend(perform_scraping(link))

print(all_reviews)
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

I hope to here from you soon.

Comment: how many reviews did you expect to get @Atharva?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your example, you aren't traversing all the pages for the reviews. Your loop goes from 1 to 2, where 2 is exclusive, but you are trying to scrape page 2.

```
def perform_scraping(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    all_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="_1AtVbE col-12-12")
    del all_div[0]
    all_reviews = []
    for review in range(0, len(all_div)):
        rating_elem = all_div[review].find("div", class_="_3LWZlK _1BLPMq")
        review_title_elem = all_div[review].find("p", class_="_2-N8zT")

        if rating_elem is not None and review_title_elem is not None:
            rating = rating_elem.text
            review_title = review_title_elem.text
            all_reviews.append((rating, review_title))
    
    return all_reviews

all_reviews = []
for page_number in range(1, 3):
    link = f"https://www.flipkart.com/prowl-tiger-shroff-push-up-board-upper-body-workout-push-up-bar/product-reviews/itm0487671f4df34?pid=BAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZ&lid=LSTBAAGM82GUHTQ3KFZVCWDQ9&marketplace=FLIPKART&page={page_number}"
    all_reviews.extend(perform_scraping(link))

print(all_reviews)
```

This is your updated code for the same.

And, I have made the code more dynamic for the pages and cleaned it up a bit.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

def perform_scraping(link):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'lxml')
    
    reviews = []
    for review in soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_27M-vq'}):
        rating = review.find('div', {'class': re.compile('_3LWZlK .*_1BLPMq')})
        review_title = review.find('p', {'class': '_2-N8zT'})

        if rating and review_title:
            reviews.append((rating.text, review_title.text))
    
    return reviews


all_reviews = []

product_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/prowl-tiger-shroff-push-up-board-upper-body-workout-push-up-bar/product-reviews/itm0487671f4df34'
response = requests.get(product_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")


if soup.find('div', {'class': '_2MImiq _1Qnn1K'}).find('span', string=re.compile('Page.* of (\d+)')):
    pages = int(soup.find('div', {'class': '_2MImiq _1Qnn1K'}).find('span', string=re.compile('Page.* of (\d+)')).text.strip().split(' ')[-1])

    for page in range(1, pages+1):
        review_page = f"{product_url}?page={page}"
        all_reviews.extend(perform_scraping(review_page))

else:
    all_reviews.extend(perform_scraping(product_url))

print(all_reviews)
```

Both of the snippets work the same for the given example, but the latter is dynamic in the sense and can work for any number of pages.

Output (First code):

```
[('4', 'Worth the money'), ('5', 'Classy product'), ('5', 'Wonderful'), ('5', 'Great product'), ('4', 'Really Nice'), ('5', 'Just wow!'), ('5', 'Highly recommended.'), ('5', 'Brilliant'), ('5', 'Terrific')]
```

Output (2nd Code):

```
[('4', 'Worth the money'), ('5', 'Classy product'), ('2', 'Moderate'), ('1', 'Very poor'), ('5', 'Wonderful'), ('5', 'Great product'), ('1', 'Waste of money!'), ('4', 'Really Nice'), ('5', 'Just wow!'), ('1', 'Useless product'), ('5', 'Highly recommended.'), ('5', 'Brilliant'), ('5', 'Terrific'), ('1', 'Utterly Disappointed')]
```

Comment: sir  thanks, but why only only 9  reviews,  in mycode I have done
`if rating_elem is not None and review_title_elem is not None` and you have done
`if rating and review_title:`. both will act same!
and third review contains both (2,moderate). Why we are not getting that.
Please help, it will be really helpful.

Comment: @Atharva, I didn't validate the output, but corrected it now, the second code works fine and the output is attached as well. The issue was, for different colored ratings there was an extra class in the `rating_elem`. As for `if rating and review_title` works the same way, as it checks whether both the elements are not `None` or `False`